# Hibernate does suboptimally queries

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I use hibernate 4.3.6, spring data jpa 1.9

I have 2 entity: DocumentOrder and OrderChain. OrderChain have ManyToOne DocumentOrders; DocumentOrder doesnt have link.

```
public class OrderChain {
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   private DocumentOrder documentOrder;
}
```

When i do query "SELECT oc FROM OrderChain oc WHERE ..." i have many requests to database(I look in console).

I find similar topics:

[preventing N+1 selects in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400285/preventing-n1-selects-in-jpa)

[FetchMode join makes no difference for ManyToMany relations in spring JPA repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891789/fetchmode-join-makes-no-difference-for-manytomany-relations-in-spring-jpa-reposi)

[JPA eager fetch does not join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463349/jpa-eager-fetch-does-not-join)

but i dont know how solve it without adding join fetch in my Query.

**edit**: I try add `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)`  to documentOrder, but it doesnt make any effect.

Thanks

Comment: This link will be helpful :https://dzone.com/articles/how-identify-and-resilve-n1

Comment: @rupesh_padhye i have many queries and add for all "join" require many time. Can i do some changes in hibernate config or in model for fix it?

Comment: There are plenty of JPA implementations and not all do "suboptimally queries", so suggest you try a different one